# Form don't submit

Tags: php, yii

I do not understand how a form submission work in yii.Help me please...

```
public function actionHome() {
    $model = new LoginForm;
    $form = new CForm('application.views.website.formV', $model);
    //protected/views/website/formV.php. 

    if($form->submitted('login') && $form->validate()){
        echo 'nig';
        $this->redirect(array('website/send'));
    }
    else {
        $this->render('login', array('form'=>$form));
    }

    echo '<h1>Hello</h1>';
    echo '<div class="form">';
    echo $form;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

FormV.php

```
return array(
    'title'=>'Label title',

    'elements'=>array(
        'username'=>array(
            'type'=>'text',
            'maxlength'=>32,
        ),


        '<div class="djada"></div>'

        ,
        /*
        'password'=>array(
            'type'=>'password',
            'maxlength'=>10,
        ),
         * 
         */
        'rememberMe'=>array(
            'type'=>'checkbox',
        )
    ),

    'buttons'=>array(
        'login'=>array(
            'type'=>'submit',
            'label'=>'Enter',
        ),
    ),
);
```

When I click  validation good but not redirect to 'website/send' ...

Another question is why the model is transmitted to new CForm...Why such a method?
How to work with it?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `$form = new CForm('application.views.website.formV', $model)`.

Comment: semicolon present in code...I think problem with $form->validate()

Comment: Did you set display_errors to On in your php.ini configuration? Check also your apache error.log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you check LoginForm class in models directory, you will find that it holds 2 public variables which are required. Required variables are username and password. Since you have commented out the password element in the form builder you will not pass the following if statement.

```
if($form->submitted('login') && $form->validate()){
```

Reason why you are redirected to new form is because it is coded that way. Once submitted() and validate() functions return true you will be redirected to website/send action instead of new login form.

Please read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder for more information about the CForm class.